Phase field of a vortex anti-vortex pair
I am just wondering if we have a vortex anti-vortex pair, what does the over all phase field look like?
I know they interact via their winding numbers, and the pair is more stable than the logarithmically divergent isolated vortex, but does this interaction deform the phase field? I would just set the overall phase field to be the sum of the individual ones, so that you get a sort of dipole looking plot (see plot)
.
Is this right or do I need to minimize a term like ($a_0$ is a UV cutoff, the positions in the plane are given and this expression comes from subbing in the vorticity to the square gradient of the phase):
$$E[\theta] \propto \ln\Big(\frac{a_0}{|x_V-x_{aV}|}\Big).$$
I think the vortices essentially interact by canceling each others divergences, so hopefully the answer is just you can add the phase fields together since they will do exactly this far away from the pair.

You need to provide the context. For example, you can have optical vortices in light where there is no interactions. Then the "dynamics" of the vortices simply comes from the properties of complex functions. In other nonlinear scenarios there could be dynamics, but that would depend on the dynamics of the theory.

The exact answer:
No you can't add.  You must go back to solving the Ginzburg-Landau equation with two defects.  Rotational symmetry is broken by the dipole-like arrangement, and of course you deform the solution along the dipole axis.
The approximate answer:
If the pair separation is way bigger than the core size, I would expect the individual vortex to be almost not distorted by its far-away partner at the scale of the core.  Then linear superposition of two copies of isolated vortex is a fair approximation.

I basically went with this. Thanks!
